# PHP: выполняются ли функции в фоновом режиме?

Tags: php, функции

Если запустить php функцию, то он будет ждать, пока она выполнится, или дальше по скрипту пойдет, выполняя ее в фоновом режиме?

Answer (score 2):

Будет ждать, пока она выполнится, за исключением функций, в описании которых сказано обратное (например, [ftp_nb_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-get.php)). Впрочем, подход с ftp_nb_get абсолютно упоротый и редко дает какой-то выигрыш из-за того, что пользователю самому приходится управлять менеджментом времени и какая-то отдельная строчка может выполняться больше, чем нужно между двумя вызовами ftp_nb_get. В нормальных языках такие задачи решаются через многопоточность, когда есть несколько потоков, у каждого есть своя задача (опросить БД / скачать файл с ФТП / обработать картинку / распарсить текст), и любой поток может остановиться, чтобы дождать выполнение какого-то другого (например, главный поток создает четыре дополнительных для парсинга четырех текстов, а после этого ждет, пока все четыре выполнятся).

Многопоточность сейчас внедряется в PHP в виде [экспериментального дополнения](http://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads), не входящего в основную коллекцию дополнений, и ей потребуется очень много времени, чтобы устаканиться (не говоря уж о том, что если такая проблема возникла, то ее надо решать, как правило, не средствами PHP). Пока что можно по старинке создавать новые системные процессы прямо из PHP, но надо иметь в виду: если каждый запрос создает дополнительный процесс, то нагрузка (условно) удвоится. Обычно все-таки висит отдельный демон-обработчик (чаще всего на питоне), которому "скармливаются" задания через SQL или полноценный IPC.